# remove from an array in a loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, collision-detection

I'm trying to create a space invaders clone in Java.

In space invaders, when a shot is fired and it hits and enemy, both objects are destroyed. This is what my code looks like:

```
while (prosessGame) {

    Drawable whatToRemove = null;
    Drawable whatToRemove2 = null;
    for (Drawable d : DrawableStuff) {

        if (!d.callTick()) {
            whatToRemove = d;
        }

        for (Drawable k : DrawableStuff) {
            if (k.rectIntersect(d.getRect()) && k != d) {
                whatToRemove = d;
                whatToRemove2 = k;
            }
        }
    }

    for (Drawable d : DrawableStuff) {
        d.callAfterTick();
    }
    DrawableStuff.remove(whatToRemove);
    DrawableStuff.remove(whatToRemove2);
```

Drawable is an interface, DrawableStuff is an array of all my instances, d.callTick() is my object's game code that returns false if the instance needs to be destroyed, d.callAfterTick is like callTick but it runs after it, and getRect is a getter for getting the instance's rectangle collision box.

Obviously this code only allows up to two instances to be destroyed at the same time. I'm wanting this code to make a list/queue/stack because if (!d.callTick) {DrawableStuff.remove(d);} and returns an error.

EDIT:

The error is when I try to remove the instance with if (!d.callTick) {DrawableStuff.remove(d);} instead of if (!d.callTick()){whatToRemove=d;} I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(Unknown Source)
at helloworld.java.Drawer.main(Drawer.java:84)
```

I assume this is because I'm using the for loop that directly uses the array, and I'm changing it half way through, I think.

What I'm looking for is a way to say this (in pseudo-code):

```
queue removeQueue
    for (Drawable d :  DrawableStuff){
    if (!d.callTick()){
    removeQueue.add(d);
    }
    -- bla bla bla--
}
for(j : removeQueue){
    Drawablestuff.remove(j);
}
```

EDIT 2:

I have changed the code to:

```
for (Iterator<Drawable> i = DrawableStuff.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
        Drawable d = i.next();

        if (!d.callTick()) {
            i.remove();
        }

        for (Iterator<Drawable> ii = DrawableStuff.iterator(); ii.hasNext();){
            Drawable dd = ii.next();
            if (dd.rectIntersect(d.getRect()) && d!=dd){
                ii.remove();
                i.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

but it returns this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
at helloworld.java.Drawer.main(Drawer.java:112)
```

the code does work as expected when I remove the second loop so it looks like this:

```
for (Iterator<Drawable> i = DrawableStuff.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ){
  Drawable d = i.next();
  if (!d.callTick()) {
    i.remove();
  }
}
```

(it only removes the projectiles when they hit the top of the screen, that's the only thing that makes things return false)

Can someone help me fix this, please? :)

Comment: "*returns an error*" What error?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to remove things from most types of `Collection`s / `Iterable`s (the interface used by foreach) while you're iterating over it by using its `Iterator` to do it directly.

Unfortunately, this means rewriting the loop as a foreach loop hides the `Iterator` on you.

```
for (Iterator<Drawable> i = DrawableStuff.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    Drawable d = i.next();

    if (!d.callTick()) {
        i.remove();
    }
}
```

Not all `Iterator`s support `remove`, but the ones for the general collections do.